# Get access to REST API using JWT security token

Tags: java, rsa, token, jwt

I have RSA key in format

```
<RSAKeyValue>
  <Modulus> ..</Modulus>
  <Exponent>..</Exponent>
 ... 
</RSAKeyValue>
```

I need to get connection to REST API using java.
I should use JWT security token with schema “TokenIssuer”.
Nimbus library provide following example for doing it. Will it help me or I need something else? If yes, where should I write RSA key?

```
// RSA signatures require a public and private RSA key pair,
// the public key must be made known to the JWS recipient in
// order to verify the signatures
KeyPairGenerator keyGenerator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
keyGenerator.initialize(1024);

KeyPair kp = keyGenerator.genKeyPair();
RSAPublicKey publicKey = (RSAPublicKey)kp.getPublic();
RSAPrivateKey privateKey = (RSAPrivateKey)kp.getPrivate();

// Create RSA-signer with the private key
JWSSigner signer = new RSASSASigner(privateKey);

// Prepare JWT with claims set
JWTClaimsSet claimsSet = new JWTClaimsSet();
claimsSet.setSubject("alice");
claimsSet.setIssueTime(new Date());
claimsSet.setIssuer("https://c2id.com");

SignedJWT signedJWT = new SignedJWT(new JWSHeader(JWSAlgorithm.RS256), claimsSet);

// Compute the RSA signature
signedJWT.sign(signer);

// To serialize to compact form, produces something like
// eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiJ9.SW4gUlNBIHdlIHRydXN0IQ.IRMQENi4nJyp4er2L
// mZq3ivwoAjqa1uUkSBKFIX7ATndFF5ivnt-m8uApHO4kfIFOrW7w2Ezmlg3Qd
// maXlS9DhN0nUk_hGI3amEjkKd0BWYCB8vfUbUv0XGjQip78AI4z1PrFRNidm7
// -jPDm5Iq0SZnjKjCNS5Q15fokXZc8u0A
String s = signedJWT.serialize();

// To parse the JWS and verify it, e.g. on client-side
signedJWT = SignedJWT.parse(s);

JWSVerifier verifier = new RSASSAVerifier(publicKey);
assertTrue(signedJWT.verify(verifier));

// Retrieve the JWT claims
assertEquals("alice", signedJWT.getJWTClaimsSet().getSubject());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my perspective, if you want use RSA, then I suggest to use nested signed and encrypted JWT. 
In that way the server can sign JWT with public key, and then the client can decrypt JWT with private key and validate that JWT.
From the perspective of storing the keys, you can store them on the file system, provide some kind configuration property to point to that file, or because it's public key, you can get that key from some services, or you can request it from the client.
Same approach you can take with storing private keys on client side.

But I think for most scenarios is acceptable to use nested signed and encrypted JWT with simple HMAC protection.
Because client will request authentication, and he will send received token to server, and the server will do validation of JWT token.
You can look at the Nimbus example http://connect2id.com/products/nimbus-jose-jwt/examples/signed-and-encrypted-jwt

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I've already done it by using this link http://connect2id.com/products/nimbus-jose-jwt/examples/jwt-with-rsa-encryption TokenIssuer was just a name of "iss" parameter in the header. By the way I quickly understood what to set in header and body when web service provide me an example of JWT token. All I needed is  to decrypt it.